# Set the language argument of the proc format to SAS

Tags: date, sas, format

I'm trying to get today's date from the system in a certain format, for example 2022Febrero01, for this I have used the following proc format, the problem is that this code returns the first letter of the month in lowercase, and I need it in capital letters, I have seen that passing LANGUAGE = Spain as an argument (in my case) I would put the F in capital letters, but it gives me a syntax error and I can't find it anywhere, could someone be so kind as to lend me a hand please? I would be enormously grateful.

```
proc format; 
  picture dtfmt (default=25)
    other = '%B%Y%0d' (datatype=date)
    language = Spanish
  ;
run;


%let date= %sysfunc(date(), dtfmt.);

%put &date.;
```

It returns to me 2022febrero01 and i want 2022Febrero01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this before your code

```
options locale = English_UnitedStates;
```